# SQL Server CEIP is causing high waits, are there any downsides to disabling it?

Tags: sql-server

One of our production servers had high waits related to SQL Server CEIP. I read a blog post from Brent Ozar, (found here:  https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/what-queries-does-microsofts-telemetry-service-run-on-your-sql-server/) about what it is and how to disable it, so I understand that, but he did not explain what the downsides to disabling it are (unless I simply missed it), if any, and when I asked and showed the query that was running, he stated it was beyond the scope of the post and he does not cover it elsewhere, so I am asking here. Are there any downsides to disabling this service? This production server runs SQL Server 2017 Enterprise and had high waits running this query according to Solarwinds DPA.

```
/* BEGIN ACTIVE SECTION (comment inserted by DPA) */

SELECT target_data

FROM sys.dm_xe_session_targets xet

WITH
(
nolock
)

JOIN sys.dm_xe_sessions xes
WITH
(
nolock
)

ON xes.address = xet.event_session_address

WHERE xes.name = ‘telemetry_xevents’

AND xet.target_name = ‘ring_buffer’

/* END ACTIVE SECTION (comment inserted by DPA) */
```

Should I be concerned? Is this something that could cause issues if I disable it? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why do you care that this query ran by CEIP was encountering waits anyway though? Is there any indication that somehow it was affecting something else by blocking or consuming excessive resources? What wait types were there?

Comment: I care because it was an unusual spike in waits. No, it was not blocking anything, but there must have been a reason there was a sudden spike. The biggest waits associated with this query are PREEMPTIVE_XE_GETTARGETSTATE, MEMORY_ALLOCATION_EXT, and XE_BUFFERMGR_ALLPROCESSED_EVENT. And it has been continuing for the past few days now.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the service and it wont cause any issues.

- you can use [this powershell](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2019/02/what-queries-does-microsofts-telemetry-service-run-on-your-sql-server/#:%7E:text=I%20Use%20this%20one%20to%20deactivate%20CEIP%20telemetry%20over%20PowerShell) script (test it first in a non prod environment).

Comment: Any possible causes for this particular query to cause so much wait all of the sudden? Have you ever seen anything like that before?